# User defined variables in stack diagrams

Tags: python-3.x, diagram

I'm not completely sure about stack diagrams yet, but as far as I know they are used to show the value of a variable in a function. But what happens if one of the variables the function uses is a user input?

example:

```
def multiplier(number)
    print(nuber*2)
```

What am I supposed to write in the stack diagram for this function? My best guess would be something like this:

```
multiplier  number --> user input
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "stack diagram". Maybe you could post an example of one? The best I can think of is when I took assembly language programming we diagrammed the allocation of memory on the stack: where the registers were saved, where the function return pointer was stored, where the arguments were stored, where each local was stored, etc. If that is what you have in mind, then `number*2` would be stored on the top of the stack where it will be passed as an argument to the `print()` function.

Comment: I'm quite sure that we aren't taking about the same thing. Here is an example of a stack diagram: http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython004.png

The diagram says that in <module> the variable line1 has the value "Bing Tiddle", and that the variable line 2 has the value "tiddle bang". It then goes on to say that in the definition of cat_twice the variable part1 also has the value "Bing Tiddle" and so on.